# What is the letter?

Tags: pattern

My mother has a prized tile. Unfortunately, I have smashed it and can only read the letters

A N A S A O

(In no particular order)

One more letter fits but is incomprehensible. Please, help me find this missing letter so I can fix it before my mother notices!

Comment: Is it a single word or two words?

Comment: It is not a word at all. (Hence the 'pattern' category)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the missing letter is

> E

Reasoning

> Each of the letters is the first letter of one of the seven continents where the continents are defined as 
>  **A**frica 
>  **N**orth America 
>  **A**sia 
>  **S**outh America 
>  **A**ntarctica 
>  **O**ceania 
>  and of course **E**urope 
>  Maybe the prized tile is a map of the world.

Comment: Very good! 100% correct.