# Need help to find more missing tiles

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

Thanks to all your help in ([What is the letter?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33644/what-is-the-letter/33665#33665)), I was able to fix my mother's tile! Unfortunately, as clumsy as I am, as I was patching this tile up, I smashed a few more. There's a letter/s missing from each set again I really need your help with these ones as they are part of one collection, and form the name of a dear friend at the end. Could you please help me again?

1) J F J M A A M J O N D

2) V G Y I R B

3) G F ; O P ; D H ; C S ; P S or S S ; H-B P

4) A B A O N W S A S

5) M M V J N U E

6) F S T F F S S E T

Hint 1:

> Try reading it.

Hint 2:

> The order is fixed.

Hint 3:

> 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 5.

Comment: Is 4) a phrase?

Comment: @jaydm26 Yes it is.

Comment: for the record, its SOPA_SN

Comment: Is it a common name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IV.

> R
>
>  A rose by any other name would smell as sweet (Romeo and Juliet)

And the name is:

> PARSONS

**Addition by OP**

Thanks to jadym26 for figuring out set 1, 2, 3 and 5 and Dan Russell for figuring out Set 6.

The full list of sets is:

> 1. Gregorian months of the year (**S**)
>  2. Popularized colors of the rainbow (**O**)
>  3. Harry Potter book titles (EN and US) (**PA**)
>  4. Shakespeare quote, Romeo and Juliet (**R**)
>  5. Planets in our Solar System (**S**)
>  6. Ordinal numbering system (**N**)

Comment: Yes! Well done!

Answer (score 8):

Partial Answer:

I.

> **S**. Months in a year.

II.

> **O**. Colors of the rainbow.

III.

> **PA**. Harry Potter books

V.

> **S**. Planets of the Solar System.

Comment: Yep, got these ones all correct.

Comment: Is the final word, an anagram formed by the letter obtained?

Comment: Yes it is an anagram.

Comment: Is the word "Passion" like Dan Russell said?

Comment: No. It is a name

Answer (score 6):

VI.

> **N** (First, Second, Third, ... Ninth is missing)

Final word

> I'm guessing **PASSION** which will be an anagram of all the missing letters.

Comment: Same. I don't know the reason for the "I" though

Comment: N is correct, Passion is not (I'm looking for a name).

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer:

I'm *guessing* that the missing letter from the fourth set is

> M

I can't figure out why it would be, but it gives you the letters to spell

> Sampson

P.S. I did figure out sets 1, 2, 3, and 5 before I saw [jaydm26's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33854/19765).

Comment: No, not Sampson (or M).